# add class to closest child

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has been asked earlier , but I am still not getting the answer
Question is if element contains text , add the class. But there are 2 elements with same class.
**For Example**

```
<div class="xyz">123</div>
<div class="add">...</div>


<div class="xyz"></div>
<div class="add">...</div>
```

Why doesnt this work?

```
if ($('div.xyz:contains("123")').length > 0) {
$(this).next(".add").addClass("long");
}
```

Comment: I don't think `$(this)` is referencing what you think it is in this case.

Comment: Just remove your conditional, and replace `this` with your selector. Or even better, use an `each` function per Anik's answer.

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('div.xyz:contains("123")').each(function(){
  $(this).next(".add").addClass("long");
})
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/95Lc4n61/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version should also work

```
$('div.xyz:contains("123") +.add ').addClass("long");
```